# In javascript, how do I call a class method from another method in the same class?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I have this:

```
var Test = new function() {  
    this.init = new function() {  
        alert("hello");  
    }
    this.run = new function() {  
        // call init here  
    }  
}
```

I want to call `init` within run. How do I do this?

Comment: There are no classes or class methods in JavaScript

Comment: @Chris Ballance Thats not *explicitly* true..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `this.init()`, but that is not the only problem.  Don't call new on your internal functions.

```
var Test = new function() {
    this.init = function() {
        alert("hello");
    };

    this.run = function() {
        // call init here
        this.init();
    };
}

Test.init();
Test.run();

// etc etc
```

Comment: But with this, I can't call `Test.init()` from another class. How do I make it so that `Test` is a singleton but still be able to call `init()` this way?

Comment: Works fine for me, firebug does not complain.  Did you remove the "new" from the function declarations inside of test?

Comment: You forgot to drop the new from the top function... The constructor

Comment: Could you update this answer for ES6, using `class`? I want to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Instead, try writing it this way:

```
function test() {
    var self = this;
    this.run = function() {
        console.log(self.message);
        console.log("Don't worry about init()... just do stuff");
    };

    // Initialize the object here
    (function(){
        self.message = "Yay, initialized!"
    }());
}

var t = new test();
// Already initialized object, ready for your use.
t.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 var Test =  function() { 
    this.init = function() { 
     alert("hello"); 
    }  
    this.run = function() { 
     // call init here 
     this.init(); 
    } 
} 

//creating a new instance of Test
var jj= new Test();
jj.run(); //will give an alert in your screen
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Test = function() {
    this.init = function() {
        alert("hello");
    } 
    this.run = function() {
        this.init();
    }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something here, you can drop the "new" from your code.

Comment: Which is perfectly fine... No?